# How to change the default values of primitive data types

Tags: mysql, null, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, primitive-types

When a `long` field is `null` in the database, eclipselink gives it a default value of `0` upon loading. How can I change that globally, so that the default value becomes `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a look in the source code of EclipseLink and I found out that this is actually easy to change, because the default value of a primitive class can be set through the api, with the method `Session.setDefaultNullValue`. (This requires using a `SessionCustomizer`.)

```
public class MySessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(final Session session) {

    DatasourceLogin login = session.getLogin();
    login.setDefaultNullValue(long.class, -1L);

  }
}
```